# Tensorflow without CUDA supported GPU

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

i have a NVIDIA GeFroce GTX 1650. This GPU is not CUDA enabled/supported ([as seen here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)). However, I still want to use Tensorflow. Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: My GPU (GeForce GTX 1050 Ti) is also not on the list, but I found a hint in the web that the list is not complete. I tried and it worked....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run `Tensorflow` on your CPU.

Use the following code block:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
import tensorflow as tf
```

If you really want to install CUDA compatible version to your graphic card, check last message [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1051268/cuda-setup-and-installation/trying-to-install-cuda-toolkit-for-use-on-gtx-1650-on-ubuntu-18-04/). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else looking for this info the GTX 1650 has compute capability of 7.5. See on the NVidia forums here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-enabled-geforce-1650/81010/2  and also on the [CUDA Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)